# This Hide function works when click anywhere on document except for elements using jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget

Tags: jquery, onclick, hide

I am styling a few Select elements with unordered () HTML lists and this function should hide those elements when a user clicks anywhere outside of the element's area, but for some reason it isn't working when the user clicks on elements which use the [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/).

**UPDATE** - I created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/ezxSF/4/ Click to open the item labeled *'UL Element'* - If you either mouseover any of the dropdown items for the *'UL Element'* or click on the document or on the other element it works as expected, but it remains opens if you click on the *'MultiSelect Element'* without mousing over any of the *'UL Element'* items.

```
$('html').click(function(e){
  if(e.target.id == 'dropdown_box1') {
            $("#select1").show();
  } else {
            $("#select1").hide();
  }
 });
```

I've also tried creating a separate function to close that element if a user clicks on a multiselect element, but that didn't work either.

```
$('.multiselect').click(function() {
    $("#select1").hide();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="dropdown_box1"><span>Select</span></div>
<div class="dropdown_container" id="dropdown_container1">  
    <ul id="select1"> 
        <!-- Several List Item Elements --> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have a separate mouseleave function which hides the list element when the user mouses off of it, but that doesn't get fired if a user clicks to open it but doesn't mouseover the list element.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dropdown_box1").click(function () {
            $("#select1").show();
        });
        var timeoutID;
        $("#select1").mouseleave(function () {
              timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
                  $("#select1").hide();
            }, 800);
        });
          $("#select1").mouseenter(function () {
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using .blur() to hide the list? You could try:

```
$("#select1").blur(function(){
     $(this).hide();
});
```

I've not used the multiselect plugin before, and I've not tested this, but I think checking for when an item loses focus is better, over adding an event to every item and checking when it's clicked. Hope that helps.

**Update:** 
There's an event for Multiselect for when it's opened. If you look at this JSFiddle I've closed the other select when this is called: http://jsfiddle.net/k8DWK/.

Comment: I'd tried that, but unfortunately that doesn't close the element with the options

Comment: Do you have a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) example I can see? Might be easier to debug it that way.

Comment: I just created one :-) http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/ezxSF/4/ To see the problem in action, click to open the item labeled 'UL Element' and then click on the 'MultiSelect Element' (without mousing over any of the items in the 'UL Element'). If you click on the document or on the other element you'll see that it works as expected

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the original answer. Hopefully that's a workable solution.